# Flexbox: Multiple containers, containers on flex items?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it bad practice to use multiple flex containers, actually flex containers on flex items ?

I have one main div which is assigned display:flex and then I have two div's and I have a `flex-grow: 1` assigned so that they fill up exactly 50% each.

Now in each DIV I have more DIVs with content inside but I wish to align that content vertically, so could I apply a `display:flex` on this too ?

Maybe I am being over paranoid about flexbox ?

I discovered flexbox lately and for me it seems to fix a lot of issues of css, so I am using it a lot.

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely fine. An element can be a flex child/item, and a flex container at the same time.

Comment: You can use it, I post a working example .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use it below is example**

```css
        .main {
            display: flex;
        }
        .child {
            flex:1;
            border:1px solid tomato;
        }
        .content {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
            flex-flow: column nowrap;
        }
        .content-child{
            padding: 5px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-child">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-child">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you had a header and footer would they be separate flex-containers?